# How would I make this into a keybinding?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, command-line

When I want to find out what might be causing lag within vim, I use the following commands

```
:profile start ~/profile.log | :profile func * | :profile file *
<do actions that cause lag>
:profile pause :noautocmd qall!
```

Is there any way I could turn these into a keybinding so I wouldn't have to type it out every time?

I've tried the following, but apparently I'm not setting it up correctly:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>O :call ProfileStart()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>o :call ProfileEnd()<CR>

function! ProfileStart()
  :profile start ~/profile.log | :profile func * | :profile file *
endfunction

function! ProfileEnd()
  :profile pause :noautocmd qall!
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate issues!

---

Firstly, adding `|` to a keybinding (officially called a map, if you don't mind me nitpicking) is tricky. It is a special character so it must be escaped. Here are two examples of how to do this:

```
nnoremap x :echo "hi" \| echo "hi2" <CR>
nnoremap x :echo "hi" <Bar> echo "hi2" <CR>
```

---

Secondly, when you are writing a vimscript function, vim is in a different mode. You do not have to have `:` to enter command mode. You're already in command mode! And you don't need to use `|` to have multiple commands on the same line.

```
function! ProfileStart()
  profile start ~/profile.log
  profile func *
  profile file *
endfunction
```

---

You're running into 2 separate problems with only 1 goal, that is confusing. Tough to debug... But you got this, good luck!

Comment: Excellent, thank you @Ari_Sweedler! 

*fist bump with explosion*